# Why is my image not swapping back?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to animate a sword "swing" in pygame.  I am using a method like this more or less.

```
def animate(self):
    self.image1 = pg.Surface((40, 30))
    self.image1.fill(255,0,0)

    self.image2 = pg.Surface((60, 20))
    self.image2.fill(0,0,255)

    self.image = self.image1
    #not the real images, but you get the point

    now = pg.time.get_ticks()
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pg.K_l] or keys[pg.K_j]:
        self.slashing = True
    else:
        self.slashing = False
    #player image starts out as self.image1
    if self.slashing:
        self.image = self.image2
        if now - self.last_slash > 750:
            self.last_slash = now
            self.image = self.image1
```

It is swapping to image two just fine, but my timer is not bringing back image one as I would like it to.  It's just staying as image2.

Comment: One problem that I see is that you override the `self.image1` with `self.image2`, so you lose the first image and can't restore it. Better use another attribute, for example `self.current_image`, to which you assign the currently active sword image. Also, define the images in the global scope or the `__init__` method, not in the `animate` method. I've got a sword slash animation example that I'll post later, but I need to polish it a bit first.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  the posted code is not exactly what I have so that it would not need 15 var's explained. but I can replicate the original and then implement it. TYVM

Comment: It's still not swapping back to the origional image.  Hmmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to switch two images, you can do something like this: When the user slashes, set the `self.image` to the second sword image and when the time is up or the user releases the key, reset `self.image` to the first sword image. I think it's easier to use an event loop and handle the event in the class in this case.

```
import pygame as pg


# Two sword images.
SWORD_IMG1 = pg.Surface((140, 140), pg.SRCALPHA)
pg.draw.polygon(
    SWORD_IMG1, pg.Color('lightskyblue1'),
    ((70, 0), (76, 10), (76, 70), (64, 70), (64, 10)))
SWORD_IMG2 = pg.transform.rotozoom(SWORD_IMG1, -90, 1)


class Sword(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = SWORD_IMG1
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.slashing = False
        self.last_slash = None

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key in (pg.K_j, pg.K_l):
                if not self.slashing:
                    # Start the slashing animation.
                    self.image = SWORD_IMG2  # Set the image.
                    self.slashing = True      
                    self.last_slash = pg.time.get_ticks()
        elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pg.K_j, pg.K_l):
                # Reset the image.
                self.image = SWORD_IMG1
                self.slashing = False

    def update(self):
        # The update method gets called once each frame.
        if self.slashing:
            self.animate()

    def animate(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_slash > 750:
            # When the anim is done, reset the image.
            self.image = SWORD_IMG1
            self.slashing = False


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    sword = Sword((100, 300), all_sprites)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            sword.handle_event(event)

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: If you want to play an animation with more than two images, you have to do it a bit differently. I can post another example if you want.

Comment: Let me know if everything is clear or if you need more help.

Comment: I will try that out, and see where I was going wrong. TYVM.  Sorry about the slow feed back hurricane slowed us down a bit.

Comment: No problem. I hope you're okay. I still have the other example if you need it.